# Swift Package Manager with Multiplatform App

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

So I am trying to publish my first Swift package. It should be available to iOS and macOS SwiftUI-based apps. This is the package I am trying publish: https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI

When I create a standalone iOS or macOS app I don't encounter any problems with the package. Everything works as expected. However, when I import the package into a Multiplatform app, I can build it on iOS but on macOS it does not work. I get an error when I try to import the package. I restarted xCode and it cannot be built. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When adding the package to the project, it is only automatically added to the iOS target and not the macOS target.

Adding it manually resolves the issue.

[image]